# DataTable is working but receive error when accessing it in JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I instantiated a datatable and it's working fine.

But I'm receiving an error when accessing it inside a JS function.  The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function

The code I'm using is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //datatable instantiation
    $('#table-servicos').DataTable({
      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    });
});

function test() {
  //checkin:1407 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function    
  $('#table-servicos').dataTable().order([2, 'desc']).draw();    
}
```

Comment: `dataTable` is not `DataTable` ...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right but has a typo. Its `DataTable` not `dataTable`. Update the code and it should work as expected. This is a very oversight with every developer *sigh!*.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//datatable instantiation
    $('#table-servicos').DataTable({
      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]
    });
});

function test() {
  $('#table-servicos').DataTable().order([2, 'desc']).draw();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the table was initialized you have to use DataTable on the table, with the uppercase D.

```
$('#table-servicos').DataTable().order([2, 'desc']).draw();
```